# Truffle vs Embark

Tags: dapp-development, framework

- Truffle
- Embark

Can anyone explain the characteristics of, and differences between, the two frameworks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is "the best" framework right now.

Truffle and Embark are comparable in terms of features and to get started quickly with your first contracts, both are fine.
Both support contract compilation and deployment and give you a general structure for your app. Furthermore, they make it easy to interface with your deployed contracts and even test them.

dApple by Nexusdev is a tool focussing on support for interconnected multi-contract applications, but better look at the documentation yourself, as I'm not very familiar with it:
https://github.com/nexusdev/dapple

You might also want to check out the following project using webpack, to conveniently deploy contracts and use them from js code:
https://github.com/uzyn/ethereum-webpack-example-dapp

Meteor is not a framework targeted at dApp development at all, but a full stack javascript framework. While propagated by some, I think it is not a natural fit for dApps, since they do not have a server side.

Comment: Even with dApps having some centralization infrastructure could be convenient. Only the trusted core must run on the world computer.

Comment: That is most certainly correct. The Ethereum Web3 vision, however, does not include such a concept (only ethereum, whisper, swarm) and I thus wanted to point out, that a true "distributed App" can be built without a server side in the meteor sense.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, at the time of this posting, there seem to be more Stack Overflow questions about Embark (1,436) than Truffle (574) by > 2:1 margin. What that statistic might or might not imply regarding the relative amount of community knowledge is open for your own interpretation.

Some statistics

```
Results Framework Search
   1436 Embark    https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embark
    574 Truffle   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truffle
```

Note, neither of the two tags show on [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) at the present time.

Comment: This merely suggests that the word 'embark' is used more often in general. Better would to look at tags (and their frequency): [`truffle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truffle) (189) and [`embark`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embark) (8).