# What Is the prime web application framework for Ethereum Dapp?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Which `web app framework` is well accepted and better suited for developing `Ethereum Dapp`? It seems that `Javascript` based frameworks have certain advantage over others. But there are popular web app frameworks available in `Ruby` and `Python` as well.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/truffle-vs-embark

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to consider in what you said, but just to give you the whole plot in one sentence:

**There's no right or wrong here and no JS (front-end) framework is more suited than another**.

They all serve a different purpose - making building client-side applications easy and scalable.

Coming back to the things you've mentioned, Ruby, Python, as well as JavaScript can be used server-side to build web applications, while JavaScript can also be used to build client-side applications (that might talk to a server).

When it comes to client-side JavaScript, chances are high you want to use a library that already implements APIs to talk to Ethereum blockchains, like [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/). However, you can use it with any of the (at the time of writing this answer) modern JS frameworks, such as Angular, Vue or React. Again, none of these make building dapps particularly easier, but you'll have to find a way to perform transactions, which is where you might want to use Web3

Comment: Hi `Pascal Percht`, thank you for the insight.  I have used `Rails` extensively building web applications. But it seems that there is not many options with `Ruby` for Ethereum, especially wrapper for `web3.js`. One reason may be because Dapp is fairly new and there is not many applications in real life other than things like `ICO` and `cryptoKitty`. I am wondering if `JS` is intrinsically suited for Ethereum better than other languages.

Comment: This makes sense. There's web3 implementations in other languages as well (but not Ruby): https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#other-implementations