# Truffle vs. Embark

Tags: truffle, drizzle, embark

Say a programmer developer a web front-end using Truffle/Drizzle. The developer moved on and a new developer, who only knows JavaScript comes along to manage and extend the Dapp. Someone told me that Embark is better than Truffle. Would it be more efficient to point the developer towards Embark?

Comment: Hi. This question has been done before: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/truffle-vs-embark